# JPA/Glassfish: persistence.xml ignored?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, glassfish

I currently have kind of a problem.

I have a small project defining a Bean and implementing this furthermore the project contains some model schemes for hibernate.

The Bean implementation looks something like this:

```
 public class TestBean implements TBean {

    @PersistenceContext
    protected EntityManager em;

    public TestBean() {
    }

    public void createEntries(User user) {
           em.persist(user);
       }
 }
```

I think that this should work fine.

My problem now is, that I did some changes in my persistence.xml but all this changes seem to be ignored. I even deleted the whole content of the persistence.xml and changed the text in it to complete nonsense - nothing changes. My question now is, if glassfish caches the persistence.xml somehow and if yes how can I avoid this caching, and if now - what am I doing wrong ??

Thank you very much :)

Comment: Did you try undeploy/ redeploy?

Comment: Do you have more than one persistence.xml in your project?

Comment: No just one, located in src/META-INF

Comment: @Pinas Should that be META-INF, not src/META_INF ?

Comment: Actually i think that META-INF is correct. But -- i figured it out, the connection was saved inside a connection pool :) Thank you all, and sorry for bothering you

Answer (score 0):

Check the artifact you're deploying: Open the actual jar file in an archiving program and verify that the file is present in `META-INF/` folder (if you're deploying an EJB module) or in `WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/` (in case of .war).